# Building a pipeline for scraping and visualizing data

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a Scrapy spider that takes all the necessary data from a website and stores it in a database. I usually run it with "scrapy runspider". When the data is stored, I would like to display it - for that I manually start a Flask server and visualize data as a graph, extracting it from the DB.

What I need to do is:

1) To run spider automatically each day. For that, I suppose, I should deploy it to a web server. But what server and how to then reach for the data that was collected?

2) To create a simple app, on the first page of which the user is asked to choose the values of the arguments to pass to the spider. Then, as there is a request, the spider should be called with these arguments. It should then return the data, and the app should process and visualize this data.

3) To deploy all this to a web server.

The problem is, I don't quite understand how to make a coherent pipeline of the process. What I tried to do is run the spider from the app with subprocess module, like

`subprocess.call(["scrapy", "crawl", f"-a countries={countries} -a  period= {period}", "news" ])`

But like this, the spider says it's missing required arguments "countries" and "period", even though I actually pass them. Moreover, I suppose that's not how things should work.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand how subprocess.call works. The way you are calling it is equivalent to the following command line:

```
scrapy crawl "-a countries={countries} -a  period= {period}" news
```

As you can see, the -a flag and the argument are put together as one argument what is not what you wanted. You just have to change a little bit in this call:

```
subprocess.call(["scrapy", "crawl", "-a", f"countries={countries}", "-a", f"period={period}", "news"])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, is it the best way to call Scrapy spider from an app?

Comment: I don't know much about scrapy, but don't they have a python library that can call spiders?

Comment: Yes apparently they have a module for this :) scrapy.crawler. I remember I already googled it, but I thought it is only possible to call it in the file where the spider is. Now I read the docs more carefully and found what I needed.